# How to prevent an iframe page from being accessed directly

Tags: javascript, iframe

Continuing with my previous question on calling iframes via jscript.. I would like to implement a security feature so that anyone who access the iframe directly is redirected to a specific page.

One of the other questions asked this but was a bit more general. The code mentioned there was:

```
if(window.top.location == window.location){
  window.location = "http://example.com/whatever/page/you/want/them/to/go/to.html";
}
```

Question: Would it suffice to tag this between the  and place it on my page.htm which is the one being called via the iframe?

Comment: @ThiefMaster is there a better approach? I reckon that in php you can kill a page if accessed directly. Is there anything similar using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

That's no "security" at all. It's just annoying. It's super-easy to circumvent (e.g. by disabling JavaScript) but it will break links from search engines.

But yes, putting that code into the page which has to be loaded in side a frame/iframe is sufficient.